# Additional/temp/extra folder is created while exporting Crystal Reports to HTML format

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

-->Additional temp folder is creating when exporting the ctystal reports to HTML format.

HTML export is only having this problem, all other export formats(.doc,.excel,.pdf..) doesn't have this issue.

Please let me know if anybody faced this problem and solution for the same.

Ex:

```
ExportOptions crExportOptions = new ExportOptions();
DiskFileDestinationOptions crDiskFileDestinationOptions = 
            new DiskFileDestinationOptions();

CString ExportPath = @"C:\"
//set path for rept file
crDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = ExportPath + "\\Reportrpt.rpt";

HTMLFormatOptions HTML40Formatopts = new HTMLFormatOptions();
crExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
crExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.HTML40;
//given destination path
HTML40Formatopts.HTMLBaseFolderName = ExportPath;
HTML40Formatopts.HTMLFileName = "default.html";
HTML40Formatopts.HTMLEnableSeparatedPages = bSeparatedPages;

crExportOptions.DestinationOptions = crDiskFileDestinationOptions;
crExportOptions.FormatOptions = HTML40Formatopts;

reportDocloc.Export(crExportOptions);
```

this code is exported the html doc to C:\Reportrpt\Default.html, 
additionalfolder "Reportrpt" is created & exported to C:\Reportrpt.

Is there any way to supress this folder creation? or wrong in my code??

thanks is advance!!

- Prsanth (Project Lead)

Comment: Does the report contain any images? It might need the sub-folder for them and other such content that isn't stored in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any reponse.....so I communicated with SAP CR people.

problem is with SAP crystal reports, they are working on this issue.

I will update you all about once I get fix/patch/sp info. from those guys.

Regards,
Prasanth.

Comment: Hi.....got workarround for this issue form SAP CR prople..... am testing.....will let know shortly..